# Using case, count, and group by in 1 query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 3 tables that I need to join, count/sum data on, and group the data. Below are very simplified versions of my tables.

```
    People p
ID 
1
2
3
    Accounts a
ID | Balance | PeopleFK
1  | 50      | 1
2  | 25      | 2
3  | 15      | 3

    Cards c
ID | Status | PeopleFK
1  | Active | 1
2  | Inact  | 1
3  | Active | 2
4  | Other  | 2
```

What I have so far:

```
select sum(a.balance),count(c.*),
case when c.status='Active' then 'Active'
case when c.status IN ('Inactive','Other') then 'Inact'
case when c.status is null then 'No Card' end as 'CardStatus'
from people p
join accounts a on p.id=a.PeopleFK
left join cards c on p.id=c.PeopleFK
group by c.status
```

Required result would be something like:

```
Balance  |  CardStatus  |  CardCount
50       |  Active      |  2
25       | Inactive     |  1
0        | NoCard       |  1
```

But my result groups by all of the Card statuses. I understand why this happens but I'm not sure how I can get around this without writing separate queries for each case.

So instead of Inactive and Other grouping together, they group apart.

I'm still toying with this but any suggestions?

Comment: Your `Accounts` table is missing data.  Can you include it please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using [`Group By`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql), the SELECT statement may only contain fields in the Group By statement or aggregate functions (like SUM or COUNT).

You can use [a Common Table Expression (CTE)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766) to consolidate the logic of building the `CardStatus` into a select statement, and then funnel that into a new query which leverages it in both the group by and select statements

```sql
;WITH BalanceCards AS (
    SELECT a.balance,
           (CASE WHEN c.status='Active'                THEN 'Active'
                 WHEN c.status IN ('Inactive','Other') THEN 'Inact'
                 WHEN c.status IS NULL                 THEN 'No Card' 
            END) AS CardStatus
    FROM people p
    JOIN accounts a ON p.id = a.PeopleFK
    LEFT JOIN cards c ON p.id = c.PeopleFK
)
SELECT bs.CardStatus, 
       SUM(bs.balance) As Total, 
       COUNT(*) As [Count]
FROM BalanceCards bs
GROUP BY bs.CardStatus
```

Comment: This is exactly the type of thing I was looking for! The only issue is that I need it to also return anyone from the people table that has an account but no card. That's what the "when c.status IS NULL' was for but I figured maybe that wouldn't work and it appears it didn't. Any ideas?

Comment: Not sure what your data looks like, but that looks like it should do what you would want via the `LEFT JOIN` and should have a `c.status` of `NULL` if there is no card entry for a particular person, but trying running the subquery on it's own before aggregating to corroborate that the data looks like that on its own

Comment: You're right -- it's the data, not the query. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is the query you want:

```
select (case when c.status = 'Active' then 'Active'
             when c.status in ('Inactive','Other') then 'Inact'
             when c.status is null then 'No Card'
        end) as CardStatus,
       count(c.PeopleFK) as CardCount, sum(a.balance) as balance
from people p join
     accounts a
     on p.id = a.PeopleFK left join
     cards c
     on p.id = c.PeopleFK
group by (case when c.status = 'Active' then 'Active'
               when c.status in ('Inactive', 'Other') then 'Inact'
               when c.status is null then 'No Card'
          end);
```

Notes:

- You want a single `case` expression to calculate the status.
- It needs to be repeated in the `GROUP BY`.
- Do not use single quotes for column aliases.  Only use single quotes for string and date constants.
- `count(c.*)` is not valid in SQL Server.

Comment: I went with the other answer using the CTE and haven't tried your suggestion, but I believe this would get me the result I want as well.